# Can there be more than one pending edit to a single post?

Tags: feature-request, support, suggested-edits

When there is a suggested edit for a post, we see something like this:

> [image]

Since another edit can't be suggested, how exactly can there be more than one pending edit?

If the answer is, as I expect, "there can't be" I suggest changing the design to put some character or different color to the link instead of showing `(1)` e.g.

> [image]

I think that in the past the number used to show number of *reviews already done* on the suggested edit but changed at some point, so also worth changing back as this might be interesting stat.

Comment: I thought that number was the count of users who reviewed the edit. Maybe the tooltip itself is misleading?

Comment: Possibly if person A begins an edit, person B begins an edit, person A submits, person B submits you might get 2 simultaneously?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi used to be, yes, but I noticed that recently it's never more than 1 so read the tooltip. If you can find instance where it's 2 or more let me know! :)

Comment: @RichardTingle nope, that would cause edit merge or conflict but would be resolved either way instantly when B submits. :)

Comment: Good to know, I assumed it allowed it through because ive never had an edit disallowed after I've clicked edit but I often see it grayed out

Comment: @RichardTingle yep as <2K user it's disabled when there is already a suggested edit. I got your first comment wrong, thinking you meant person B is 2K+ user... in case he's <2K user he'll be greeted with an error message when submitting as far as I can tell. I might be wrong though, that's the main reason for asking first before just suggesting to change it.

Comment: @Sha, I double-checked and the number indeed remains stuck to `1` even if two users have reviewed the suggested edit. Looks like we could do without that number in the first place, then.

Answer (score 1):

> If the answer is, as I expect, "there can't be" I suggest changing the design to put some character or different color to the link instead of showing (1) e.g.

Your basis for suggesting to change it to something else makes sense, but the (1) adds something that a star or different colour doesn't indicate:

**It clearly communicates that one thing is pending here.**

A fancy star would make me wonder why there's a fancy star (do I get bonus points for editing this post?). A different colour link would make me wonder why the other links aren't also coloured, like links normally are. There are a lot of ways to distinguish the link, but...

**In internet lingo, everyone nowadays understands that if there is something with a (1) beside it, there is one thingy of some kind waiting there for them - whatever that thingy is.**

You understand what this means:

> [image: Facebook notifications]

And you understand what this is:

> [image: New Stack Exchange notification]

So when you see this:

> [image: One pending edit notification]

... if you don't *already immediately* understand what the (1) is probably for, once you click it, you'll understand pretty quickly why you're being showed a pending edit dialog: not because there's someone else out to collect the bonus star points, but because there's one edit pending.

**The fact there's never going to be a (2) is beside the point, when the (1)'s purpose is just to make this clear communication that there's a single edit waiting.**

Comment: While you do have a point, I still don't think `(1)` is proper. But of course, this might be only me! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if mods can see an edit trail, but I edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765434/select-multiple-column-from-multiple-table-and-every-two-tables-have-an-idenetit) earlier today.  2 minutes later, an edit was accepted for someone else, and mine actually fixed something theirs didn't.  So, yes I'd say it's possible to have 2 pending edits to a post.  It's probably a rare occurance, but it's possible.

Comment: Was your rejected by the community? Im not seeing yours in the edit history

Comment: Look at the revision history.  No suggested edits have been approved on that post.  Your suggested an edit, someone else was editing the post at the same time as you, but they had 2k+ rep, so their edit won by definition when the edits conflicted.  It is not possible to have two pending suggested edits on a post; if there are conflicting edits one of them will always "win" based on some automatic criteria, and the losing suggestion is automatically rejected.

Comment: @RichardTingle [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2913143) is the review in question.

Comment: Ahhh. OK, my bad. I wondered why mine didn't even show up in the revision history, I just assumed mine was tossed in favor of theirs. I wonder why the community rejected it when it included one more fix than the one that got accepted? Was it just because the other person had 2K+ rep?

Comment: Typical edit conflict. :)

Comment: @JohnnyBones I specifically answered that in my previous comment.  When a <2k rep user and a >2k rep user's edits conflict the >2k rep user wins.  You lost.

Comment: And I didn't even get a consolation waffle.  :o(  No biggie, I was just curious.  Now I know!