# I clicked "skip" in the review queue, but I've decided that I want to vote "leave open". Can I do it?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

There was this question up for closure in the review queue. I wasn't sure so I clicked "skip." But then, later, when I saw the question again, I decided that I'd like to vote "leave open". But since I clicked "skip", the question is obviously gone from the review queue.

Is it impossible for me to vote "leave open" now?

Comment: I know that I could VTC after clicking 'Leave Open' by accident in the queue by going to the question...

Comment: @Mithrandir Sure, you can always go the question and *close*. But there doesn't appear to be any *leave open* button outside of the review queue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The item is not gone from the review queue, it just won't be served to you anymore.

You can still find it by following those steps: (using MSE for sake of example, but it fits any site)

1. Go to the [review queue history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/history).
2. Click "my review history" in the bottom:

   > [image]
3. Make sure "show skipped reviews" is ticked:

   > [image]
4. In there you can see items you skipped:

   > [image]
5. Click the "Skip" link and you'll get directly to the item. You can still review it as usual.

Comment: Yeah, works like a charm :)

Comment: Cheers, I thought there's a dupe but couldn't find. Maybe my desire for rep hindered my efforts though... :P

Comment: Haha... If you couldn't find the dupe, then I'll assume there isn't one :)

Comment: @Fiksdal nah, even wizards have blind spots... more than once I asked duplicate question myself! [Exhibit A](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208350), [Exhibit B](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196768) and I'm pretty sure I even asked a question just to find it was asked before... by me!!!

Comment: Haha, ok :) Anyway, at 74k I'm not sure if your "desire for rep" is a major motivator :)

Comment: Oh, that desire never stops. What do you think drives Jon Skeet? ;-)

Comment: Haha. A desire to help people, according to himself :)

Comment: I mean, Jon Skeet probably maxes out the rep cap every day on SO, even if he doesn't post anything, because of people upvoting his old posts, lol :)

Comment: BTW, wish I could give an extra  +1 for painting skillz.

Comment: @Fiksdal lol thanks, I get lots of practice here on MSE... :-D

Comment: I'm inclined to downvote because of the lack of an overwhelming number of arrows.

Comment: @Dea I prefer circles over arrows. No sharp edges this way. ;)